# Getting error while Get parameters from restapi and use that parameter in python AWS

Tags: python-3.x

API

> https://******.****.amazonaws.com/prod/api/users/{ID}

I want to pass ID in URL and get that id using AWS lambda function through Python.

I have to access that id through python.

Python Code is

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):  
   dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
   table = dynamodb.Table('Users')
   response = table.get_Item(key={'ID':event['pathParameters']['ID']});    
  return response
```

Comment: Clarify what you want to do, and what's the issue, if you got any error mention it. And also include your solution you have tried so far.

Comment: i want to pass ID in URL and get that id using AWS lambda function through Python, am used above code , ultimately i have to access that id through python